# crash on shutdown (probably the finishActivityAffinity)

Tags: android

while finishing activity some time getting below error for some devices.
**Android: 5.1.1**

while finish activity with this line got below error  **ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(this);**

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'com.android.server.am.TaskRecord com.android.server.am.ActivityRecord.task' on a null object reference
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1499)
    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.finishActivityAffinity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2790)
    at android.app.Activity.finishAffinity(Activity.java:4752)
    at com.frostwire.android.gui.activities.MainActivity.shutdown(MainActivity.java:177)
    at com.frostwire.android.offers.Offers$AdNetworkHelper.dismissAndOrShutdownIfNecessary(Offers.java:280)
    at com.frostwire.android.offers.AppLovinInterstitialAdapter.adHidden(AppLovinInterstitialAdapter.java:119)
    at com.applovin.adview.AppLovinInterstitialActivity.c(Unknown Source)
    at com.applovin.adview.AppLovinInterstitialActivity.dismiss(Unknown Source)
    at com.applovin.adview.q.onClick(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Share your code please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: at this line ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(this); crash happened